# "Billing not supported" error in Google Play

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

Firstly I have been googling for goodness knows how long and have followed several other question's answers to no avail.

I have an Android application with in-app purchases, using the test keys (android.test.purchased) everything works fine. Using my actual product I get the following error:

```
This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play.
```

I have followed the steps outlined by both Google and various StackOverflow answers:

1. Upload a signed APK to Google Play (not published)
2. Setup an in-app item (published)
3. Install the same APK onto the phone.
4. Ensure your google account (from the phone) is listed as a tester in Google Play.
5. Add public key to billing code.
6. Wait for some time just in-case!

I still get the problem mentioned above. What could I be missing??

Edit:
A thought that has come to mind, does it matter what you use to sign the exported APK with?

Comment: cross check your `.apk` file... as the only reason of the error is miss match of `.apk` files

Comment: @Naeem I have exported from eclipse (Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package) and uploaded that file. Then using the same file I have copied that to my phone (via dropbox) and then installed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never like to answer my own questions, as it always looks like I'm after the rep which I am not!!

After much trying I finally managed to get this to work, it appears that you need to wait around 6 hours for an apk to be recognized as valid for in-app purchases. What is strange is that if you upload the APK during the early morning (UK time) it gets through the system faster (US/UK lag!?).

So to sum up for anyone that may have come across this answer, just be patient!!

Comment: Don't worry, because you don't earn the reputation for your own accepted answers. You will for your upvotes, but that's deserved anyway for any additional information someone writes.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Google Play should improve their messages and meke them more informative.

Answer (score 0):

There is one obvious thing missing: setting your public key in the billing library code.

> *Edit: A thought that has come to mind, does it matter what you use to sign the exported APK with?*

Yes, you must sign it in release mode [[1](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)]. Export the application in Eclipse, and when it prompts you for a certificate, point to your .keystore file. Follow the steps and you'll have your apk signed with your release key.

Comment: sorry forgot to add that to the list! Public key is present.

Comment: Just to make sure: you're signing with a production key, right?

Comment: The "key" that I am using in the billing code is the one from "Licensing & In-app Billing" in the developer console. What I mean in my edit is, does it matter what key/passphrase is used when you export the apk from eclipse.